# CSS HTML img position absolute

Tags: html, css

Ok,
So I have made an interactive map, when users go with their mouse over one or red dots they get a little information screen.

But it slides a little when people with smaller screens view the web page:
example:

[image: This is a screenshot of how it should look]

This screenshot shows how it should look:

Screen minimized

[image]

As you can see, the green and red dots get out of place, and I want to prevent this from happening.

Code:

```
<div style="position: relative; left: 0; top: 0;">
    <img src="images/overhead.png" width="1000" height="1000" style="position: relative; top: 0; left: 0;"/>
    <img src="images/taken.png" class="masterTooltip" height="18" width="18" title="This house is owned by:&nbsp;<?php echo $owner ?>" style="position: absolute; top: 400px; left: 960px;"/>
</div>
```

Remeber, this:

```
<img src="images/taken.png" class="masterTooltip" height="18" width="18" title="This house is owned by:&nbsp;<?php echo $owner ?>" style="position: absolute; top: 400px; left: 960px;"/>
```

Does one dot in the map.
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two solutions here, either assign a static `width` to the container element or you need to use `%`.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/6EvVg/1/) *(Fixed `width` wrapper element)*

Also, you might want to take a look at [`<map>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/map) tag as well.

Answer (score 0):

you can add the size of image in css with percent. 
for example if you add

```
height:100%;
width:100%;
```

when the screen get smaller or bigger, your images has 100% width and height in screen.

Comment: Image will be resized automatically, you don't have to specify `%` for that, the issue is the absolute positioned elements won't stay at the right place